# How to parse JSON results from Unirest call

Tags: java, android, json, unirest, mashape

I'm using the [Unirest library](http://unirest.io/java.html) to retrieve JSON from a Mashape API. I have the call working using the following code:

```
HttpResponse<JsonNode> request = Unirest.get(URL)
  .header("X-Mashape-Authorization", MASHAPE_AUTH)
  .asJson();
```

This returns my JSON in the form of `HttpResponse<JsonNode>`, which I am unfamiliar with.

From reading the limited [documentation](http://unirest.io/java.html), It seems that I have to call `getBody()` on the response object in order to get a JsonNode object back. I still have no idea what to do with the JsonNode object however.

What is the best way to begin to parse this data?

**Edit:**
In case it helps with giving examples, the JSON I want to parse looks like this:

```
{
  "success": "1",
  "error_number": "",
  "error_message": "",
  "results": [
    {
      "name": "name1",
      "formatedName": "Name 1"
    },
    {
      "name": "testtesttest",
      "formatedName": "Test Test Test"
    },
    {
      "name": "nametest2",
      "formatedName": "Name Test 2"
    },
    {
      "name": "nametest3",
      "formatedName": "Name Test 3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I have been unable to find any document that details this part of the library. Hence me asking the question. Have you used the Unirest library? Do you know of any good documentation to help me?

Comment: Try to print JsonNode.toString() and let me know what it will show you...

Comment: @Haresh, Just tried that and it prints out the Json that I am after. Exactly like the json i've edited into my main post.

Comment: The docs at http://unirest.io/java.html seem to indicate you are on your own with regard to parsing the JSON, and suggest using Jackson. Is it just me, or is this far less handy than `groovyx.net.http.RESTClient` which returns a `response` object where any arbitrary JSON key can be retrieved by `response.data.blah`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Was trying to figure this out today for myself. The source code is probably the only documentation you're going to get. Here's the tl;dr

```
// the request from your question
HttpResponse<JsonNode> request = Unirest.get(URL)
  .header("X-Mashape-Authorization", MASHAPE_AUTH)
  .asJson();

// retrieve the parsed JSONObject from the response
JSONObject myObj = request.getBody().getObject();

// extract fields from the object
String msg = myObj.getString("error_message");
JSONArray results = myObj.getJSONArray();
```

Here's some more explanation of the spelunking I did:

From [the HttpResponse class](https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mashape/unirest/http/HttpResponse.java) we can see that `getBody()` is going to return the instance variable `body`, which gets assigned on line 92 as:

```
this.body = (T) new JsonNode(jsonString)
```

So then we need to look at [the JsonNode class](https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mashape/unirest/http/JsonNode.java). The constructor takes a string representing the JSON to be parsed and attempts to create either a `JSONObject` or a `JSONArray`. Those objects come from `org.json` which is [well documented](https://web.archive.org/web/20150407014519/http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html), thankfully.

Comment: Shouldn't `JSONObject myObj = request.getBody().getObject();` be `JSONObject myObj = response.getBody().getObject();` ?

Answer (score 9):

As the response is easily retrieved as a String, you can use any JSON library you want for deserialzion if you don't want to walk through the JSON manually.  I personally am partial to Google's GSON and its ability to easily map your JSON response to an object that you create to match.

```
HttpRequest request = Unirest.get(/*your request URI*/)
                .headers(/*if needed*/)
                .queryString(/*if needed*/);

HttpResponse<JsonNode> jsonResponse = request.asJson();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String responseJSONString = jsonResponse.getBody().toString();
MyResponseObject myObject = gson.fromJson(responseJSONString, String.class);
```

Comment: This makes no sense, why would you use asJson and then toString when there is asString?

Answer (score 5):

In a JSON string , there are two symbols that guide you through parsing :

{ - indicates a JSONObject

[ - indicates a JSONArray

When parsing a json string, you should go through this items iteratively. To understand how many JsonObjects and JsonArrays you have in your string , and from which you should start parsing, use a json-visualizer tool like [this website](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/). for exampl for your string the structure is like this :
[image]

As you see, the root object is a JSONObject which consists of an JSONArray with three jsonOnjects. To parse such a structure you can use :

```
JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject(jsonstring);

String result = jsonObject.getString("success");
String error_number = jsonObject.getString("error_number");    
String error_message = jsonObject.getString("error_message"); 

JSON Array jsonarray = jsonobj.getJSONArray();

String[] names = new String[jsonArray.length()];    
String[] formattedNames = new String[jsonArray.length()];  

for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
{
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

    names [i] = jsonObject.getString("name");
    formattedNames [i] = jsonObject.getString("formattedName");
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a Serialization feature in Unirest (probably came out after the answers in 2015 and 2014). With the current version 1.4.9, you can use the handy asObject(Class) and body(Object) methods. Here is an example of deserializing AWS CloudSearch responses.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.ObjectMapper;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException;

public class UnirestExample {
    public class Item {
        private String full4kurl;
        private String previewurl;
        private String description;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "{full4kurl:" + full4kurl + ", previewurl:" + previewurl
                    + ", description:" + description + "}";
        }
    }

    public class Hit {
        private String id;
        private Item fields;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "{id:" + id + ", fields:" + fields + "}";
        }
    }

    public class Hits {
        private int found;
        private int start;
        private Hit[] hit;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "{found:" + found + ", start:" + start + ", hit:"
                    + Arrays.toString(hit) + "}";
        }
    }

    public class CloudSearchResult {
        private Hits hits;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "{hits:" + hits + "}";
        }
    }

    public static final String END_POINT = "AWS CloudSearch URL";

    static {
        Unirest.setTimeouts(1000, 5000);

        Unirest.setObjectMapper(new ObjectMapper() {
            private Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping()
                    .create();

            @Override
            public <T> T readValue(String value, Class<T> valueType) {
                return gson.fromJson(value, valueType);
            }

            @Override
            public String writeValue(Object value) {
                return gson.toJson(value);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnirestException {
        HttpResponse<CloudSearchResult> response = Unirest.post(END_POINT)
                .header("Header", "header").body("body")
                .asObject(CloudSearchResult.class);
        if (response.getStatus() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            CloudSearchResult body = response.getBody();
            System.out.println(body);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Fail to invoke URL ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the body of JsonNode and then convert the JsonNode to JSONObject to access the values. In order to access the results, you can convert it to JSONArray.

```
import org.json.*;
HttpResponse<JsonNode> request = Unirest.get(URL).header("X-Mashape 
Authorization", MASHAPE_AUTH).asJson();
JSONObject responsejson = request.getBody().getObject();
JSONArray results = responsejson.getJSONArray("results");
```

Then you can iterate over each JSONObject in results. For example to get first object in results

```
JSONObject value = results.getJSONObject(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work as it worked for me

```
System.out.println(request.getBody().getObject().toString(2));
```

**sample code**

```
import com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.JsonNode;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest;

public class UnirestClient{
public void getQuestions() throws Exception {
HttpResponse<JsonNode> stack= Unirest.get("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions").
    header("accept",  "application/json").
    queryString("order","desc").
    queryString("sort", "creation").
    queryString("filter", "default").
    queryString("site", "stackoverflow").
    asJson();
System.out.println(stack.getBody().getObject().toString(2));
 }

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
JavaHTTPAPIClient client = new JavaHTTPAPIClient();
client.getQuestionsUsingUnirest();
 }
}
```

**Response**

```
    {
      "quota_max": 300,
      "items": [
        {
          "creation_date": 1477998742,
          "tags": [
            "javascript",
            "spring",
            "sockjs",
            "spring-js",
            "sockjs-tornado"
          ],
          "title": "Sockjs 404 not found",
          "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358911/sockjs-404-not-found",
          "score": 0,
          "answer_count": 0,
          "owner": {
            "display_name": "Sviatlana",
            "accept_rate": 71,
            "user_type": "registered",
            "profile_image": "https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9utH.jpg?s=128&g=1",
            "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/5288347/sviatlana",
            "reputation": 109,
            "user_id": 5288347
          },
          "last_activity_date": 1477998742,
          "question_id": 40358911,
          "view_count": 2,
          "is_answered": false
        },
        {
          "creation_date": 1477998741,
          "tags": [
            "php",
            "html",
            "email",
            "magento",
            "static-block"
          ],
          "title": "Creating a magento email template: custom static block not working",
          "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358910/creating-a-magento-email-template-custom-static-block-not-working",
          "score": 0,
          "answer_count": 0,
          "owner": {
            "display_name": "Elliot",
            "user_type": "registered",
            "profile_image": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3ca06bfc99ca77598a8c58aa0945bc8a?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1",
            "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/6914645/elliot",
            "reputation": 3,
            "user_id": 6914645
          },
          "last_activity_date": 1477998741,
          "question_id": 40358910,
          "view_count": 1,
          "is_answered": false
        },
        {
          "creation_date": 1477998733,
          "tags": [
            "vba",
            "random",
            "macros",
            "numbers",
            "powerpoint"
          ],
          "title": "Random number Powerpoint as slide change",
          "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358908/random-number-powerpoint-as-slide-change",
          "score": 0,
          "answer_count": 0,
          "owner": {
            "display_name": "Luca ",
            "user_type": "registered",
            "profile_image": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/50594e4723d9c9235a49385e70fdc347?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1",
            "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/7099333/luca",
            "reputation": 1,
            "user_id": 7099333
          },
          "last_activity_date": 1477998733,
          "question_id": 40358908,
          "view_count": 2,
          "is_answered": false
        },
        {
          "creation_date": 1477998717,
          "tags": [
            "javascript",
            "jquery",
            "cordova",
            "jquery-mobile"
          ],
          "title": "page redirection happening when Go button is pressed on a textbox (jquery/cordova)",
          "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358903/page-redirection-happening-when-go-button-is-pressed-on-a-textbox-jquery-cordov",
          "score": 0,
          "answer_count": 0,
          "owner": {
            "display_name": "Abhi",
            "accept_rate": 58,
            "user_type": "registered",
            "profile_image": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/118f3b090dbf70bbb82dd280ed2f4e24?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1",
            "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/5145530/abhi",
            "reputation": 536,
            "user_id": 5145530
          },
          "last_activity_date": 1477998717,
          "question_id": 40358903,
          "view_count": 3,
          "is_answered": false
        },
        {
          "creation_date": 1477998684,
          "tags": [
            "php",
            "wordpress",
            "for-loop"
          ],
          "title": "Wordpress: looping through alternating post types and outputting featured image",
          "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358895/wordpress-looping-through-alternating-post-types-and-outputting-featured-image",
          "score": 0,
          "answer_count": 0,
          "owner": {
            "display_name": "icabob91",
            "user_type": "registered",
            "profile_image": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4955d4f2e9bcbdee92ef49ffd76c51d6?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1",
            "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/6104799/icabob91",
            "reputation": 3,
            "user_id": 6104799
          },
          "last_activity_date": 1477998684,
          "question_id": 40358895,
          "view_count": 3,
          "is_answered": false
        },
        {
          "creation_date": 1477998678,
          "tags": [
            "python",
            "datetime",
            "python-3.5",
            "timedelta"
          ],
          "title": "datetime difference in python3.5",
          "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358893/datetime-difference-in-python3-5",
          "score": 0,
          "answer_count": 0,
          "owner": {
            "display_name": "gansub",
            "accept_rate": 85,
            "user_type": "registered",
            "profile_image": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ac74b6d927012828dbd79279614f3e58?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1",
            "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/4033876/gansub",
            "reputation": 237,
            "user_id": 4033876
          },
          "last_activity_date": 1477998678,
          "question_id": 40358893,
          "view_count": 4,
          "is_answered": false
        },
        {
          "creation_date": 1477998668,
          "tags": [
            "arm",
            "tensorflow"
          ],
          "title": "Wipe out dropout operations from TensorFlow graph",
          "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358892/wipe-out-dropout-operations-from-tensorflow-graph",
          "score": 0,
          "answer_count": 0,
          "owner": {
            "display_name": "Dmytro Prylipko",
            "accept_rate": 40,
            "user_type": "registered",
            "profile_image": "https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVfpi.png?s=128&g=1",
            "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/2641587/dmytro-prylipko",
            "reputation": 98,
            "user_id": 2641587
          },
          "last_activity_date": 1477998668,
          "question_id": 40358892,
          "view_count": 2,
          "is_answered": false
        },
        {
          "creation_date": 1477998668,
          "tags": [
            "c++",
            "qt"
          ],
          "title": "Scale a dynamically added widget",
          "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358891/scale-a-dynamically-added-widget",
          "score": 0,
          "answer_count": 0,
          "owner": {
            "display_name": "student",
            "accept_rate": 88,
            "user_type": "registered",
            "profile_image": "https://graph.facebook.com/814890818587238/picture?type=large",
            "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/4621626/student",
            "reputation": 43,
            "user_id": 4621626
          },
          "last_activity_date": 1477998668,
          "question_id": 40358891,
          "view_count": 3,
          "is_answered": false
        },
        {
          "creation_date": 1477998642,
          "tags": ["sql"],
          "title": "SQL returning different rows based on certain conditions",
          "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358889/sql-returning-different-rows-based-on-certain-conditions",
          "score": 0,
          "answer_count": 0,
          "owner": {
            "display_name": "clueless83",
            "user_type": "registered",
            "profile_image": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/c99db40aa014047b39b6e8222c120d84?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1",
            "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/6720789/clueless83",
            "reputation": 18,
            "user_id": 6720789
          },
          "last_activity_date": 1477998642,
          "question_id": 40358889,
          "view_count": 10,
          "is_answered": false
        },
        {
          "creation_date": 1477998626,
          "tags": [
            "angularjs",
            "select",
            "multiple-select"
          ],
          "title": "Angular: Select multiple in chrome ( in firefox work perfectly)",
          "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358886/angular-select-multiple-in-chrome-in-firefox-work-perfectly",
          "score": 0,
          "answer_count": 0,
          "owner": {
            "display_name": "Enrique Rubio Sanchez",
            "user_type": "registered",
            "profile_image": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-jKUZPfGsMEY/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAHY/aisyHc_Xlm4/photo.jpg?sz=128",
            "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/5496817/enrique-rubio-sanchez",
            "reputation": 11,
            "user_id": 5496817
          },
          "last_activity_date": 1477998626,
          "question_id": 40358886,
          "view_count": 5,
          "is_answered": false
        },
        {
          "creation_date": 1477998622,
          "tags": [
            "c#",
            "coloranimation"
          ],
          "title": "Cannot animate the color property because the object is sealed or frozen",
          "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358884/cannot-animate-the-color-property-because-the-object-is-sealed-or-frozen",
          "score": 0,
          "answer_count": 0,
          "owner": {
            "display_name": "Wobbles",
            "accept_rate": 63,
            "user_type": "registered",
            "profile_image": "https://graph.facebook.com/100003846611758/picture?type=large",
            "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/3797778/wobbles",
            "reputation": 1691,
            "user_id": 3797778
          },
          "last_activity_date": 1477998622,
          "question_id": 40358884,
          "view_count": 3,
          "is_answered": false
        },
        {
          "creation_date": 1477998619,
          "tags": [
            "paypal",
            "laravel-5.2",
            "paypal-rest-sdk"
          ],
          "title": "Integrating Paypal Rest API to laravel 5.2 using anouarabdsslm",
          "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358882/integrating-paypal-rest-api-to-laravel-5-2-using-anouarabdsslm",
          "score": 0,
          "answer_count": 0,
          "owner": {
            "display_name": "Ankit Jindal",
            "user_type": "registered",
            "profile_image": "https://graph.facebook.com/100001546390988/picture?type=large",
            "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/4198180/ankit-jindal",
            "reputation": 6,
            "user_id": 4198180
          },
          "last_activity_date": 1477998619,
          "question_id": 40358882,
          "view_count": 2,
          "is_answered": false
        },
        {
          "creation_date": 1477998605,
          "tags": [
            "decimal",
            "dynamics-crm-2016",
            "editablegrid"
          ],
          "title": "Dynamcis CRM EditableGrid sdoesn&#39;t sets quantity to 0",
          "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358881/dynamcis-crm-editablegrid-sdoesnt-sets-quantity-to-0",
          "score": 0,
          "answer_count": 0,
          "owner": {
            "display_name": "ODE",
            "accept_rate": 71,
            "user_type": "registered",
            "profile_image": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3607bfe0c1a853e890ff5c746e793856?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1",
            "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/3332226/ode",
            "reputation": 82,
            "user_id": 3332226
          },
          "last_activity_date": 1477998605,
          "question_id": 40358881,
          "view_count": 2,
          "is_answered": false
        },
        {
          "creation_date": 1477998604,
          "tags": [
            "reporting-services",
            "parameters",
            "mdx"
          ],
          "title": "MDX (SSRS) Parameter subset",
          "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358880/mdx-ssrs-parameter-subset",
          "score": 0,
          "answer_count": 0,
          "owner": {
            "display_name": "user2181700",
            "accept_rate": 67,
            "user_type": "registered",
            "profile_image": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a973bbc5607eb4bf001c1d0587c2035d?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG",
            "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/2181700/user2181700",
            "reputation": 40,
            "user_id": 2181700
          },
          "last_activity_date": 1477998604,
          "question_id": 40358880,
          "view_count": 2,
          "is_answered": false
        },
        {
          "creation_date": 1477998588,
          "tags": [
            "bash",
            "chef-recipe"
          ],
          "title": "How can I loop through bash routine in Chef?",
          "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358877/how-can-i-loop-through-bash-routine-in-chef",
          "score": 0,
          "answer_count": 0,
          "owner": {
            "display_name": "user5241806",
            "accept_rate": 38,
            "user_type": "registered",
            "profile_image": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f93135e0156fd5d3ecba4935a42c0c47?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1",
            "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/5241806/user5241806",
            "reputation": 63,
            "user_id": 5241806
          },
          "last_activity_date": 1477998588,
          "question_id": 40358877,
          "view_count": 3,
          "is_answered": false
        },
        {
          "creation_date": 1477998584,
          "tags": [
            "entity-framework",
            "asp.net-web-api",
            "unity-container"
          ],
          "title": "Dependency injection not working in web api call",
          "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358875/dependency-injection-not-working-in-web-api-call",
          "score": 0,
          "answer_count": 0,
          "owner": {
            "display_name": "Tom",
            "accept_rate": 71,
            "user_type": "registered",
            "profile_image": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/71cd701f6826481858ee299f68f3205a?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1",
            "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/4607841/tom",
            "reputation": 94,
            "user_id": 4607841
          },
          "last_activity_date": 1477998584,
          "question_id": 40358875,
          "view_count": 5,
          "is_answered": false
        },
        {
          "creation_date": 1477998573,
          "tags": [
            "c++",
            "windows",
            "process",
            "kill",
            "termination"
          ],
          "title": "How to prevent a windows application from being killed/terminate or stop",
          "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358872/how-to-prevent-a-windows-application-from-being-killed-terminate-or-stop",
          "score": 0,
          "answer_count": 0,
          "owner": {
            "display_name": "Ankush Dhingra",
            "user_type": "registered",
            "profile_image": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/136386aece9fd21861cb2b42f24f81b6?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1",
            "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/7099310/ankush-dhingra",
            "reputation": 1,
            "user_id": 7099310
          },
          "last_activity_date": 1477998573,
          "question_id": 40358872,
          "view_count": 6,
          "is_answered": false
        },
        {
          "creation_date": 1477998556,
          "tags": [
            "python",
            "azure",
            "arm",
            "azure-sdk-python"
          ],
          "title": "Azure python sdk for VM Resource Monitoring",
          "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358870/azure-python-sdk-for-vm-resource-monitoring",
          "score": 0,
          "answer_count": 0,
          "owner": {
            "display_name": "KMG",
            "accept_rate": 26,
            "user_type": "registered",
            "profile_image": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3632d43837fe92fda15ddf3b6ad5a8c2?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1",
            "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/3524468/kmg",
            "reputation": 158,
            "user_id": 3524468
          },
          "last_activity_date": 1477998556,
          "question_id": 40358870,
          "view_count": 3,
          "is_answered": false
        },
        {
          "creation_date": 1477998521,
          "tags": [
            "javascript",
            "arrays",
            "for-loop"
          ],
          "title": "JavaScript array 2 dimension for loop",
          "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358865/javascript-array-2-dimension-for-loop",
          "score": 0,
          "answer_count": 0,
          "owner": {
            "display_name": "Rayan Suryadikara",
            "accept_rate": 80,
            "user_type": "registered",
            "profile_image": "https://graph.facebook.com/959947287411964/picture?type=large",
            "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/5355995/rayan-suryadikara",
            "reputation": 28,
            "user_id": 5355995
          },
          "last_activity_date": 1477998521,
          "question_id": 40358865,
          "view_count": 24,
          "is_answered": false
        },
        {
          "creation_date": 1477998512,
          "tags": [
            "javascript",
            "user-interface",
            "kendo-ui",
            "grid"
          ],
          "title": "How to set the number format for hyperlinks in kendo grid column",
          "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358863/how-to-set-the-number-format-for-hyperlinks-in-kendo-grid-column",
          "score": 0,
          "answer_count": 0,
          "owner": {
            "display_name": "Harsha vardhan Reddy",
            "user_type": "registered",
            "profile_image": "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-tnuvSHlig1U/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAdU/pBo7JDjmBpM/photo.jpg?sz=128",
            "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/6323557/harsha-vardhan-reddy",
            "reputation": 1,
            "user_id": 6323557
          },
          "last_activity_date": 1477998512,
          "question_id": 40358863,
          "view_count": 2,
          "is_answered": false
        },
        {
          "creation_date": 1477998507,
          "tags": [
            "android",
            "achartengine"
          ],
          "title": "aChartEngine; getCurrentSeriesAndPoint returns null",
          "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358862/achartengine-getcurrentseriesandpoint-returns-null",
          "score": 0,
          "answer_count": 0,
          "owner": {
            "display_name": "Hyunin",
            "user_type": "registered",
            "profile_image": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ddaf10ed143d2d44f9a1de00dc6465ec?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1",
            "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/7099269/hyunin",
            "reputation": 1,
            "user_id": 7099269
          },
          "last_activity_date": 1477998507,
          "question_id": 40358862,
          "view_count": 2,
          "is_answered": false
        },
        {
          "creation_date": 1477998499,
          "tags": [
            "c#",
            "selenium",
            "selenium-chromedriver"
          ],
          "title": "Uploading a file with Selenium C#",
          "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358860/uploading-a-file-with-selenium-c",
          "score": 0,
          "answer_count": 0,
          "owner": {
            "display_name": "Hoverlord",
            "user_type": "registered",
            "profile_image": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-5spNCjwaRtU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAADUo/CWI4U9m0VWw/photo.jpg?sz=128",
            "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/7099290/hoverlord",
            "reputation": 1,
            "user_id": 7099290
          },
          "last_activity_date": 1477998499,
          "question_id": 40358860,
          "view_count": 4,
          "is_answered": false
        },
        {
          "creation_date": 1477998487,
          "tags": [
            "javascript",
            "unit-testing",
            "angular2",
            "typescript",
            "jasmine"
          ],
          "title": "Angular 2 with jasmine: test component with injected service",
          "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358858/angular-2-with-jasmine-test-component-with-injected-service",
          "score": 0,
          "answer_count": 0,
          "owner": {
            "display_name": "DavidL",
            "accept_rate": 81,
            "user_type": "registered",
            "profile_image": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ce4583fa48bbd2e762ba0a9aaeab7909?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1",
            "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/4656551/davidl",
            "reputation": 483,
            "user_id": 4656551
          },
          "last_activity_date": 1477998487,
          "question_id": 40358858,
          "view_count": 5,
          "is_answered": false
        },
        {
          "creation_date": 1477998486,
          "tags": [
            "c#",
            "jquery",
            "ajax",
            "routes",
            "asp.net-core-mvc"
          ],
          "title": "asp.net core id value in route doesn&#39;t work with ajax",
          "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358857/asp-net-core-id-value-in-route-doesnt-work-with-ajax",
          "last_edit_date": 1477998683,
          "score": 0,
          "answer_count": 0,
          "owner": {
            "display_name": "Anton Toshik",
            "accept_rate": 86,
            "user_type": "registered",
            "profile_image": "https://graph.facebook.com/1259984217361793/picture?type=large",
            "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/5784635/anton-toshik",
            "reputation": 27,
            "user_id": 5784635
          },
          "last_activity_date": 1477998683,
          "question_id": 40358857,
          "view_count": 9,
          "is_answered": false
        },
        {
          "creation_date": 1477998481,
          "tags": [
            "python",
            "string",
            "python-3.x",
            "machine-learning",
            "string-matching"
          ],
          "title": "how to generate a set of similar strings in python",
          "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358855/how-to-generate-a-set-of-similar-strings-in-python",
          "score": 0,
          "answer_count": 0,
          "owner": {
            "display_name": "daiyue",
            "accept_rate": 82,
            "user_type": "registered",
            "profile_image": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/55fd0f7d95a4938975026ff886c3a563?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG",
            "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/766708/daiyue",
            "reputation": 806,
            "user_id": 766708
          },
          "last_activity_date": 1477998481,
          "question_id": 40358855,
          "view_count": 8,
          "is_answered": false
        },
        {
          "creation_date": 1477998477,
          "tags": [
            "java",
            "mysql",
            "swing",
            "connection-pooling"
          ],
          "title": "Does Connection Pooling makes Java Swing Application works faster for remote MySQL database",
          "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358852/does-connection-pooling-makes-java-swing-application-works-faster-for-remote-mys",
          "score": 0,
          "answer_count": 0,
          "owner": {
            "display_name": "user2200561",
            "accept_rate": 25,
            "user_type": "registered",
            "profile_image": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/1b7fb8ee134a1d1fdb25350e74c3322c?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG",
            "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/2200561/user2200561",
            "reputation": 8,
            "user_id": 2200561
          },
          "last_activity_date": 1477998477,
          "question_id": 40358852,
          "view_count": 5,
          "is_answered": false
        },
        {
          "creation_date": 1477998469,
          "tags": [
            "python",
            "apache",
            "hadoop",
            "mapreduce",
            "apache-pig"
          ],
          "title": "Apache Pig - nested FOREACH over same relation",
          "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358849/apache-pig-nested-foreach-over-same-relation",
          "score": 0,
          "answer_count": 0,
          "owner": {
            "display_name": "user2817219",
            "accept_rate": 60,
            "user_type": "registered",
            "profile_image": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/89b91c209b145ead1e1a4309fc048afc?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1",
            "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/2817219/user2817219",
            "reputation": 65,
            "user_id": 2817219
          },
          "last_activity_date": 1477998469,
          "question_id": 40358849,
          "view_count": 4,
          "is_answered": false
        },
        {
          "creation_date": 1477998456,
          "tags": [
            "mysql",
            "laravel-5",
            "eloquent"
          ],
          "title": "column overridden by another column with same name when using join method in eloquent",
          "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358846/column-overridden-by-another-column-with-same-name-when-using-join-method-in-elo",
          "score": 0,
          "answer_count": 0,
          "owner": {
            "display_name": "Mazino S Ukah",
            "accept_rate": 100,
            "user_type": "registered",
            "profile_image": "https://graph.facebook.com/933943226659646/picture?type=large",
            "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/5746074/mazino-s-ukah",
            "reputation": 125,
            "user_id": 5746074
          },
          "last_activity_date": 1477998456,
          "question_id": 40358846,
          "view_count": 5,
          "is_answered": false
        },
        {
          "creation_date": 1477998428,
          "tags": [
            "javascript",
            "http",
            "caching",
            "browser"
          ],
          "title": "Tell the browser to drop cache of image",
          "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358839/tell-the-browser-to-drop-cache-of-image",
          "score": 0,
          "answer_count": 0,
          "owner": {
            "display_name": "php_nub_qq",
            "accept_rate": 86,
            "user_type": "registered",
            "profile_image": "https://i.stack.imgur.com/daMab.jpg?s=128&g=1",
            "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/2415293/php-nub-qq",
            "reputation": 5811,
            "user_id": 2415293
          },
          "last_activity_date": 1477998428,
          "question_id": 40358839,
          "view_count": 8,
          "is_answered": false
        },
        {
          "creation_date": 1477998422,
          "tags": [
            "ios",
            "certificate",
            "keychain",
            "p12"
          ],
          "title": "Keychain asking password for importing p12 but i didn&#39;t give password",
          "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358836/keychain-asking-password-for-importing-p12-but-i-didnt-give-password",
          "score": 0,
          "answer_count": 0,
          "owner": {
            "display_name": "Olcay Erta?",
            "accept_rate": 92,
            "user_type": "registered",
            "profile_image": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f164c6c3b709c97862a0d14f7725830b?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG",
            "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/614065/olcay-erta%c5%9f",
            "reputation": 1129,
            "user_id": 614065
          },
          "last_activity_date": 1477998422,
          "question_id": 40358836,
          "view_count": 2,
          "is_answered": false
        }
      ],
      "has_more": true,
      "quota_remaining": 298
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

        String respone  = "{\n" +
               "  \"success\": \"1\",\n" +
               "  \"error_number\": \"\",\n" +
               "  \"error_message\": \"\",\n" +
               "  \"results\": [\n" +
               "    {\n" +
               "      \"name\": \"name1\",\n" +
               "      \"formatedName\": \"Name 1\"\n" +
               "    },\n" +
               "    {\n" +
               "      \"name\": \"testtesttest\",\n" +
               "      \"formatedName\": \"Test Test Test\"\n" +
               "    },\n" +
               "    {\n" +
               "      \"name\": \"nametest2\",\n" +
               "      \"formatedName\": \"Name Test 2\"\n" +
               "    },\n" +
               "    {\n" +
               "      \"name\": \"nametest3\",\n" +
               "      \"formatedName\": \"Name Test 3\"\n" +
               "    }\n" +
               "  ]\n" +
               "}";

        try{

            JSONObject responeJson = new JSONObject(respone);
            if(responeJson.getString("success").equals("1")){
                JSONArray jsonArray = responeJson.getJSONArray("results");

                for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                    System.out.println("Name : "+jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
                    System.out.println("FormatedName : "+jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("formatedName"));
                }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this,responeJson.getString("error_message"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }catch (Throwable e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```