# Apache Pig - nested FOREACH over same relation

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have a number of bags and I want to compute the pairwise similarities between the bags.

```
sequences = FOREACH raw GENERATE gen_bag(logs);
```

The relation is described as follows:

```
sequences: {t: (type: chararray, value:charray)}
```

The similarity is computed by a Python UDF that takes two bags as arguments. I have tried to do a nested foreach over the sequences variable, but I cant loop over the same relation twice. I've also tried to define the sequences twice, but I cant access the copy in the foreach. I'm also unsure how I can come up with a data structure that allows me to do things like this. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could load up two copies of the source data, perform a cross-product, then iterate through calling your UDF on each pair. Something like:

```
sequences_A = FOREACH raw GENERATE gen_bag(logs);
sequences_B = FOREACH raw GENERATE gen_bag(logs);
all_pairs = CROSS sequences_A, sequences_B;
FOREACH all_pairs GENERATE myudf(first_bag, second_bag);
```