# Does Connection Pooling makes Java Swing Application works faster for remote MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc, connection-pooling

I have Created an Java Swing Application with MySQL as the database, Now i am hosting my MySQL database online and Swing Application will be stored locally, Now in order to experiment i have hosted my database i.e MySQL database on https://www.freemysqlhosting.net/ account as it allows free hosting for certain period, Also Connection is successfull and works but the application works too slow suppose if i have to search any entry from the swing aplication from the oline hosted database it works too slow,it is happening like i have to press any key or button and has to wait for the processing of the transaction. Does connection pooling technique will solve the performance issues, If yes which is best one and if not what can i do to solve this. Please Help

Below is the code which i have written to make database transactions and i am doing this everytime i make a database access

```
public  ArrayList<ChargeSheet> readByAllCompanyInfo(String cityname)
{
ArrayList<ChargeSheet> list = new ArrayList<ChargeSheet>();
con=db.getConnection();
try{
    pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from tblcompanyinformation where companyname = ?");
    pst.setString(1,cityname);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()){
        ChargeSheet clientInformation=new ChargeSheet();
        clientInformation.setRecieptno(rs.getInt(2));
        clientInformation.setPresentdate(rs.getString(3));
        clientInformation.setCompanyname(rs.getString(4));
        clientInformation.setPhone(rs.getString(5));
        list.add(clientInformation);   
    }
}
catch(SQLException ex){
    setLastError(ex.getMessage());
}
finally{
    db.closeConnection();
}
return list;   
}
```

Comment: It depends, for example do you currently open and close connections for each database access, or do you open one connection and keep it open for the lifetime of the application? If the first, then yes connection pooling can improve performance, if the second then not likely.

Comment: Yes the first one i open and close connections for each database access

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel i dont have anything like session or lifetime of the application, At present if i have to do without connection pooling i have to open the connection and keep it for the life time of the application could you please tell me how can i do it. I will show the code where i am opening and closing the application each time i make database access i will edit my Question above

Answer (score 0):

With that code, it is likely that using a connection pool will improve performance.  Especially if you are using SSL-enabled connections.

(Of course, this assumes that you use the same pool for connecting.)

> If yes which is best one ....

Recommendations are Off-Topic for StackOverflow, but I'm sure you could find a website that lists and compares some popular alternatives.