# how to generate a set of similar strings in python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, machine-learning, string-matching

I am wondering how to generate a set of similar strings based on `Levenshtein distance` (string edit distance). Ideally, I like to pass in, a source string (i.e. a string which is used to generate other strings that are similar to it), the number of strings need to be generated and a threshold as parameters, i.e. similarities among the strings in the generated set should be greater than the threshold. I am wondering what `Python` package(s) should I use to achieve that? Or any idea how to implement this?

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can think of the problem in another way (reversed).

- Given a string, say it is **sittin**.
- Given a threshold (edit distance), say it is `k`.
- Then you apply combinations of different "edits" in k-steps.

For example, let's say k = 2. And assume the allowed [edit modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) you have are:

- delete one character
- add one character
- substitute one character with another one.

Then the logic is something like below:

```
input = 'sittin'
for num in 1 ... n:  # suppose you want to have n strings generated
  my_input_ = input
  # suppose the edit distance should be smaller or equal to k;
  # but greater or equal to one
  for i in in 1 ... randint(k): 
    pick a random edit mode from (delete, add, substitute)
    do it! and update my_input_
```

If you need to stick with a pre-defined dictionary, that adds some complexity but it is still doable. In this case, the edit must be valid.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing heavily on the pseudocode in [@greeness answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40373101/5299417) I thought I would include the code I used to do this for DNA sequences.
This may not be your exact use case but I think it should be easily adaptable.

```
import random
dna = set(["A", "C", "G", "T"])

class Sequence(str):

    def mutate(self, d, n):
        mutants = set([self])
        while len(mutants) < n:
            k = random.randint(1, d)
            for _ in range(k):
                mutant_type = random.choice(["d", "s", "i"])
                if mutant_type == "i":
                    mutants.add(self.insertion(k))
                elif mutant_type == "d":
                    mutants.add(self.deletion(k))
                elif mutant_type == "s":
                    mutants.add(self.substitute(k))
        return list(mutants)


    def deletion(self, n):
        if n >= len(self):
            return ""
        chars = list(self)
        i = 0
        while i < n:
            idx = random.choice(range(len(chars)))
            del chars[idx]
            i += 1
        return "".join(chars)

    def insertion(self, n):
        chars = list(self)
        i = 0
        while i < n:
            idx = random.choice(range(len(chars)))
            new_base = random.choice(list(dna))
            chars.insert(idx, new_base)
            i += 1
        return "".join(chars)

    def substitute(self, n):
        idxs = random.sample(range(len(self)), n)
        chars = list(self)
        for i in idxs:
            new_base = random.choice(list(dna.difference(chars[i])))
            chars[i] = new_base
        return "".join(chars)
```

To use this you can do the following

```
s = Sequence("AAAAA")
d = 2  # max edit distance
n = 5  # number of strings in result
s.mutate(d, n)
>>> ['AAA', 'GACAAAA', 'AAAAA', 'CAGAA', 'AACAAAA']
```