# asp.net core id value in route doesn't work with ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I am making something like a chat room application, and when you enter a chat room I use the room id to assign messages to that room, I am using Ajax to send and retrieve messages.

Map Route:

```
config.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Room", action = "Index" });
```

Navigation to room:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" asp-controller="Chat" asp-action="Index" asp-route-id="@room.Id">@room.Name</a>
```

So when you are in a room the Route is like so `"localhost/Chat/{id}"`

Chat Controller (for specific room):

```
[Route("/Chat/{id:int}")]
public IActionResult Index(int id)
{
    return View();
}

[Route("/Chat/{id:int}/GetChat")]
public IActionResult GetChat()
{
    return PartialView("_Chat", _repository.getAllMessages());
}
```

I am using a value of `1` for the id to test this.

```
$.ajax({
    url: rootUrl + "Chat/1/GetChat",
    type: "GET",
    traditional: true,
    success: function (data) {
        //do stuff
    },
    error: function () {
        //do stuff
    }
```

rootUrl is set in _Layout like so

```
rootUrl = '@Url.Content("~")'
```

Whats the best way to make AJAX calls work for specific route with an id?

Comment: Use a relative path, not an absolute one. Also, I'd strongly suggest you use websockets over AJAX for a chat application

Comment: Also note that you have a syntax error with the `function` that's in no-man's land after the `success` handler.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that was a typo, would you be able to show how to use a relative path?

Comment: `url: 'FooAction'` Would result in `domain.com/chat/1/fooaction` - assuming you're calling it from your `Index` action

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it is called from the index action however it only works with `url: "1/GetChat" `

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I can't make it use the id as part of the absolute path

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127161/discussion-between-anton-toshik-and-rory-mccrossan).