# JavaScript array 2 dimension for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I want to define a two dimensional array object with for loop... my problem I think my object didn't really get processed, here's the code :

```
var newLoc = [];

var index;

for (index = 0, i < locations.length; i++){
                if(i == 0) {
                    newLoc[i][0] = locations[i][1];
                    newLoc[i][1] = locations[i][2];
                }
                else {
                    if(locations[i][8] == locations[i-1][8]){
                        newLoc[i-1][0] = (locations[i][1] + locations[i-1][1])/2;
                        newLoc[i-1][1] = (locations[i][2] + locations[i-2][1])/2;    
                    }                            
                    else{
                        newLoc[i][0] = locations[i][1];
                        newLoc[i][1] = locations[i][2];
                    }
                }
            }
```

locations array itself is the old array which store the data for new array (newLoc). locations' data are existing which are coordinate latitude and longitude. I suppose there is something wrong with my for loop form or how I declare newLoc 2 dimension array, but I still don't know how to fix it. Any help appreciated.

Comment: `for (index = 0, i < locations.length; i++){` should be `for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++){` right? ( note the `;`)

Comment: you declared variable index but in for loop used i for iteration. should be: `var i; for(i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {...}`. and i can't understand how it should works.

Comment: thanks to point those out :)

Answer (score 2):

There are some things you can do with your code for optimization. First you have to initialize your loop correctly. then inside the loop, it is better to assign the value statically rather checking it every time for only one implementation. This should optimize your code. The old location posting could make the following code more optimized.

```
var newLoc = [];

if(locations.length > 0){
    for(var j = 0; j < 1; ++j) {
        newLoc[j] = [ ];

        newLoc[j][0] = locations[0][1]; 
        newLoc[j][1] = locations[0][2];

    }

}

for (var i = 1, i < locations.length; i++){

    if(locations[i][8] == locations[i-1][8]){
        newLoc[i-1][0] = (locations[i][1] + locations[i-1][1])/2;
        newLoc[i-1][1] = (locations[i][2] + locations[i-2][1])/2;    
    }                            
    else{
        newLoc[i][0] = locations[i][1];
        newLoc[i][1] = locations[i][2];
    }                
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but do you know how to check if newLoc's value?

Comment: In the same way as the location's value is checked. I guess it will be like     **if(locations.length > 0)**

Comment: In the same way as the location's value is checked. I guess it will be like if(newLoc.length > 0) –

Comment: I mean, to check it in browser?

Comment: hahaha...sorry i did not understand. just use console.log(newLoc) for checking it in the console. Dont forget to upvote me :P Good Day..:)

Comment: defining `var newLoc = [];` will throw an error on `newLoc[0][0]`. There's nothing at index `0`

Comment: Thanks for identifying. I did not checked the code. I have updated the code to fix the issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that newLoc is always a 1 dimentionnal array and you declare 'index' in your for loop but use 'i' in the body

```
var newLoc = [];

// loop with 
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++){
    //Create the second dimention
    newLoc[i] = [];
            if(i == 0) {
                    ...
```

Comment: okay, still not working.... anyone know how to see the value of newLoc? Check it if the value already defined in the array

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed, in your `for` loop, you have written

```
for (index = 0, i < locations.length; i++)
```

instead of

```
for (index = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
```

**Note the `;`**

So, in all the loop should be

```
for (index = 0; i < locations.length; i++){
            if(i == 0) {
                newLoc[i][0] = locations[i][1];
                newLoc[i][1] = locations[i][2];
            }
            else {
                if(locations[i][8] == locations[i-1][8]){
                    newLoc[i-1][0] = (locations[i][1] + locations[i-1][1])/2;
                    newLoc[i-1][1] = (locations[i][2] + locations[i-2][1])/2;    
                }                            
                else{
                    newLoc[i][0] = locations[i][1];
                    newLoc[i][1] = locations[i][2];
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing a one-dimensional array, so, when you iterate over the loop, your javascript code will probably you break.

Try to initialize using this way:

```
var newLoc = new Array(locations.length).fill(locations.length);
```

Array Doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array