# Azure python sdk for VM Resource Monitoring

Tags: python, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-sdk-python

I can retrieve the VM state by using Azure python sdk. Now I tried to get the VMs resource usage [ CPU, bandwith, disk ]. But unable to find the option for it.

Someone please share the link if its available,.

Comment: @Notlikethat , any idea ?

Comment: I haven't the slightest idea, as the only thing I know about Azure Resource Manager is that it has bog all to do with the ARM CPU architecture ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have full-packaged support for that currently. I suggest you to follow this issue on the Python SDK Github account:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/555

It's on the close roadmap.

(I'm the guy in charge of the Python SDK at MS)

Comment: Thank you so much for your update. will track that github issue.