# How to prevent a windows application from being killed/terminate or stop

Tags: c++, windows, process, kill, termination

I have a windows c++ application which runs under the normal (non-admin) user. I want that no user should be able to close/stop/terminate this application by any means.

Is there any active directory group policy available to achieve this or I need to do some programming for the same

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know is that your app will launch run 2 or more  background processes that check every few ms that your app and the other backgrounds are running, if not it re-launches them.This makes it very had or impossible to terminate your app manually.

You application might need to save its state to disk , if it needs to re-launch to the same stat is was when destroyed

Answer (score -1):

you can also disable the close button or whatever can terminate your application. Also disable the taskmanager so users cannot kill your application

Comment: Ctrl + shift + escape, select the process, kill....

Answer (score -1):

There is a technique called **hooking** which will allow injection of your code into Windows DLL's, altering certain behaviours performed by the operating system.

This would prevent the operating system killing these proccesses using the core DLL's.

There is a downside to this method though as it may flag up as a virus on anti-rootkit systems as this is a technique often used to prevent the user from killing an infection.