# Dependency injection not working in web api call

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, unity-container

Hi I am trying to build angular 2 web  application using WebAPI, Entityframework that is loosely coupled using dependency injection. I am using unity for dependency injection. I have created multiple projects in one solution to address the separation concerns.

I have configured the dependency in unity.config however when i execute the webapi application and type the following url http://localhost:8702/api/allcustomers   , I get message saying the customer controller doesn't have parameter-less constructor. I have set my break points in unity.config which never get hit

I would like to to understand if my implementation is correct as well

Below is the structure of my solution

CustomerOrder.Business.Objects
CustomerOrder.Data.Objects (references the business object)
CustomerOrder.Service.Api (references business object and service implementation)
CustomerOrder.Service.Implementation (references business objects and data objects)
CustomerOrder.Web (Yet to implement)

Below is the code

**CustomerOrder.Business.Objects**

```
 public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }

        public int? Zip { get; set; }

    }
```

**CustomerOrder.Data.Objects**

```
    public class CustomerDao : ICustomerDao
        {

            IEnumerable<CustomerOrder.BusinessObjects.Customer> ICustomerDao.GetAllCustomers()
            {
                using (var customerOrderContext = new Entities())
                {
                    return (from customer in customerOrderContext.Customers

                            select new CustomerOrder.BusinessObjects.Customer
                            {
                                Id = customer.Id,
                                FirstName = customer.FirstName,
                                LastName = customer.LastName,
                                Address = customer.Address,
                                City = customer.City,
                                Email = customer.Email,
                                Gender = customer.Gender,
                                State = customer.State,
                                Zip = customer.Zip
                            }).ToList();
                }
            }
      }


    public interface ICustomerDao
        {

            /// <summary>
            /// Get All Customers
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns></returns>
            IEnumerable<Customer> GetAllCustomers();

        }

        public interface IDaoFactory
        {
            ICustomerDao CustomerDao { get; }

        }
    }

  public class DaoFactory : IDaoFactory
    {
        public DaoFactory(ICustomerDao CustomerDao, IProductDao ProductDao, IOrderDao OrderDao)
        {
            this.CustomerDao = CustomerDao;
        }

        public ICustomerDao CustomerDao { set; get; }





    }
```

**CustomerOrder.Service.Api**

```
Unity.Config 

    public static void RegisterComponents()
            {
                var container = new UnityContainer();

                // register all your components with the container here
                // it is NOT necessary to register your controllers

                // e.g. container.RegisterType<ITestService, TestService>();

                container.RegisterType<ICustomerProvider, CustomerProvider>();
                container.RegisterType<IOrderProvider, OrderProvider>();
                container.RegisterType<IProductProvider, ProductProvider>();

                GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
            }

CustomerController.cs

    public class CustomerController : ApiController
        {
            private ICustomerProvider customerProvider;


            public CustomerController(ICustomerProvider customerProvider)
            {
                this.customerProvider = customerProvider;
            }

            [Route("api/allcustomers")]
            public IEnumerable<Customer> GetAllCustomers()
            {
                return customerProvider.GetAllCustomers();
            }
```

**CustomerOrder.Service.Implementation**

```
public interface ICustomerProvider
{

    IEnumerable<BusinessObjects.Customer> GetAllCustomers();

}

 public class CustomerProvider : ICustomerProvider
    {

        private readonly IDaoFactory dataAccess;

        public CustomerProvider(IDaoFactory dalFactory)
        {
            this.dataAccess = dalFactory;
        }

        public IEnumerable<BusinessObjects.Customer> GetAllCustomers()
        {
            IList<BusinessObjects.Customer> customerCollection = new List<BusinessObjects.Customer>();
            dataAccess.CustomerDao.GetAllCustomers();
            return customerCollection;
        }
}
```

Context Class

```
namespace CustomerOrderData.EF
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class Entities : DbContext
    {
        public Entities()
            : base("name=Entities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
         //   throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well you haven't registered your controllers. I'm not familiar with Unity, but there's probably a single line you're missing here.

Comment: Where did you call the `RegisterComponents()` method? seems it is not being called

Comment: Its in the unity.config. Its there in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *CustomerProvider*, the *IDaoFactory* is probably not getting resolved because it's not registered.  Add this to the `Unity.Config`:

```
container.RegisterType<IDaoFactory , DaoFactory >();
```

Comment: Do I need to install unity in ServiceImplementation project as well because it there where I am trying to inject IDaoFactory. Currently I have installed unity in web.apii project

Comment: @Tom...All registrations are done in the root (the controller's assembly)

Comment: I have registered the DaoFactory in unity.config but that seems to have not resolved the issue yet.

Comment: Are you calling Unity.Config from Global.asax?

Comment: I hadnt so far but after you mentioned , I added the line in Global.asax.    UnityConfig.RegisterComponents(); . I am getting error An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'CustomerController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

Comment: Make sure RegisterComponents() is called.  In the error message, it may tell you that it's unable to resolve a ctor parameter.  What is it?  Something in your call stack is not getting injected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127118/discussion-between-tom-and-big-daddy).

Comment: The current type, CustomerOrder.Data.Objects.ICustomerDao, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

Comment: Add ICustomerDao to your Unity registrations

Comment: The error has gone but it seems to pull no records. There are 36 rows in the customer table.

Answer (score 0):

Please try including a parameterless constructor into the customer controller.

```
public CustomerController() {}
```

Comment: You are right. With parameterless constructor my  injection doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

You should register not only IDaoFactory and his constructor dependencies

```
container.RegisterType<IDaoFactory, DaoFactory>();
container.RegisterType<ICustomerDao, CustomerDao>();
container.RegisterType<IOrderDao, OrderDao>();
container.RegisterType<IProductDao, ProductDao>();
```

Comment: i had already done this. I have update my post with the context class. The approach that I had used was database first. Not sure if I have to do anything in the context class. At the moment there is no error but returns no data

Comment: I have also checked the application logs in Event Viewer .Not exception. The SQL Profiler does show query request to customers table.

Comment: While debugging , I can  see error in the customerdao class in the GetAllCustomers() method. The customerorderContext.Customers object throws object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: This is not Unity problem, just mark answer what solves the problem and i suppose you are alreading searching while EF LazyLoading is not working