# MDX (SSRS) Parameter subset

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, mdx

I need a bit of help with my SSRS parameter code in MDX 
**context** 
I'm trying to return Country locations with and type = matter and a house count (not used as a parameter) 
for the drop down list 
I'm using the caption, uniqueName and level.ordinal method

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterCaption] AS
 [Country].[Location].CurrentMember.Member_Caption 
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterCaption2] AS
 [Type].[Type].CurrentMember.Member_Caption
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterValue] AS
[Country].[Location].CurrentMember.UniqueName
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterLevel] AS 
[Country].[Location].CurrentMember.Level.Ordinal
SELECT 
{ [Measures].[HouseCount]
, [Measures].[ParameterCaption]
,[Measures].[ParameterValue]
,[Measures].[ParameterLevel]}ON COLUMNS
,  ([Type].[Type].ALLmembers )ON ROWS
FROM [Cube];
```

this doesn't return what I'm after

[image]

I should be shown a list of locations only where they are crossed with a type =matter and has a House count 
I when I tweak the code either get all location or what is show table the value of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to move `[Country].[Location]` into context and type into a `WHERE` clause?

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterCaption] AS
   [Country].[Location].CurrentMember.Member_Caption 
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterCaption2] AS
    [Type].[Type].CurrentMember.Member_Caption
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterValue] AS
    [Country].[Location].CurrentMember.UniqueName
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterLevel] AS 
    [Country].[Location].CurrentMember.Level.Ordinal
SELECT 
    {
      [Measures].[HouseCount],
      [Measures].[ParameterCaption],
      [Measures].[ParameterValue],
      [Measures].[ParameterLevel]
    } ON COLUMNS,
    NonEmpty(
      [Country].[Location].[Location].MEMBERS
     ,[Measures].[HouseCount]
    ) ON ROWS
FROM [Cube]
WHERE [Type].[Type].[matter];
```

Comment: Do you also need to filter to rows with a house count? Maybe change the ON ROWS clause to `NonEmpty([Country].[Location].[Location].MEMBERS, [Measures].[HouseCount]) ON ROWS` and see if that does it

Comment: thanks @GregGalloway I missed that bit of their request

Answer (score 0):

You have no filtering in your query as it is currently written. To achieve what you state (only return where `Type` is `matter`) then simply select only that Type on the ROWS.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterCaption] AS
   [Country].[Location].CurrentMember.Member_Caption 
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterCaption2] AS
    [Type].[Type].CurrentMember.Member_Caption
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterValue] AS
    [Country].[Location].CurrentMember.UniqueName
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterLevel] AS 
    [Country].[Location].CurrentMember.Level.Ordinal
SELECT 
    {
      [Measures].[HouseCount],
      [Measures].[ParameterCaption],
      [Measures].[ParameterValue],
      [Measures].[ParameterLevel]
    } ON COLUMNS,
    ( [Type].[Type].[matter] ) ON ROWS
FROM [Cube];
```

Comment: hi guys because [Measures].[ParameterCaption] is selected even with Where statement it returns all locations not just the ones where the type is matter