# SQL returning different rows based on certain conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm sure if this is possible in SQL but my combination of case statements and wheres aren't working.  This is some test data in the shape I'm using..

[image]

It shows items in an Order.  In this order, the customer has amended the order for pens and increased the amount to 15.  So the original order item, id 123, is marked as superceded and a new item row is created, id 158, and the PreviousVersion column is populated with the previous items itemId.  AmendedStatusId is the status of the amended item.  So in the example ItemId 158 is the updated version of ItemId 123.  And the extra pens haven't been paid as they are AwaitingApproval.  I know it's not the best laid out data but it's what I've to work with.

What I'm trying to do is when the amended items haven't been paid to select the old item, so in this example return ItemIds 123 and 124.  When AmendedStatusId of ItemId 123 is updated to Paid, I would want to return ItemId 124 and 158.  Is this possible?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) What happens if an order line changes more than once?

Comment: Everytime an Item is amended, another record is added to the table.  So the new change will look like ItemId 158, and the previous ones will be similar to ItemId 123.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: How can you tell 124 is linked to 158/123?  124 does not appear in the `PreviousVersion` column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of structure should get you started.

```
select isnull(paidItemId, unpaidItemId) itemId
from yourTables
left join (subquery to identify paid items) paidItems on something
left join (subquery to identify unpaid items) unpaidItems on something
etc
```