# How to rewrite a tensorflow graph to use CPU for all operations

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I've trained a network on a multi GPU and CPU setup, and saved the resulting model as a tensorflow `SavedModel`. I then have another script which can load the resulting model and run the required ops to make a prediction, i.e., run inference on the model. This works on the same setup that the model was trained on.

However, I need to deploy the model to run on a device with 1 CPU and no GPUs. When I try to run the same script, I get these errors:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Restoring from checkpoint failed. This is most likely due to a mismatch between the current graph and the graph from the checkpoint. Please ensure that you have not altered the graph expected based on the checkpoint. Original error:
>
> Cannot assign a device for operation default_policy_1/tower_1/Variable: node default_policy_1/tower_1/Variable (defined at restore.py:56) **was explicitly assigned to /device:GPU:0** but available devices are [ /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0, /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_CPU:0 ]. Make sure the device specification refers to a valid device. **The requested device appears to be a GPU, but CUDA is not enabled.**
> [[node default_policy_1/tower_1/Variable (defined at restore.py:56) ]]

This looked promising but the code did not change my graph at all, 0 nodes were removed - [Remove operation graph tensorflow to run on CPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54590442/remove-operation-graph-tensorflow-to-run-on-cpu)

In general it doesn't seem wise to just remove every operation that doesn't run on CPU anyway

I've tried wrapping everything in a `with tf.device('CPU:0')` block, as well as using `config = tf.ConfigProto(device_count={'GPU': 0})` but neither changed the error.

Relevant code:

```py
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import loader

input_tensor_key_feed_dict = {'observations': np.array([[23]]), 'prev_action': np.array([0]),
                              'prev_reward': np.array([0]), 'is_training': False}

config = tf.ConfigProto(device_count={'GPU': 0})
with tf.device('CPU:0'):
    with session.Session(None, graph=ops_lib.Graph(), config=config) as sess:
        
        loader.load(sess, tag_set.split(','), saved_model_dir) #error occurs here
        
        outputs = sess.run(output_tensor_names_sorted, feed_dict=inputs_feed_dict)
        for i, output in enumerate(outputs):
            output_tensor_key = output_tensor_keys_sorted[i]
            print('Result for output key %s:\t%s' % (output_tensor_key, output))
```

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37660312/how-to-run-tensorflow-on-cpu?

Comment: I have that exact line in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would initialize a new model without device specifications and then load only the model variables as it would be a standard training checkpoint with tf.Saver(). At this point you should be able to save a version of your SavedModel for which tensorflow can decide where to place the ops.

Comment: I trained the model on with GPU, then instantiated another model with CUDA disabled. Copying over the weights from the first model to the other works perfectly.