# page redirection happening when Go button is pressed on a textbox (jquery/cordova)

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am working on a cordova app and using jquery mobile with cordova.

I have created a text field in the html page in the following manner:

```
<input type="email" id="email_id" name="email_id" maxlength="80" placeholder="email@doamin.com" style="height: 50px;" />
```

when I set focus on this field and press Go button (ASCII code = 13) from the mobile's keyboard, I am redirected to the login page of my application(which is also the 1st page of my app) and the page stack appears something like this:

```
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
hash: "#page_settings"
lastScroll: 156
pageUrl: "page_settings"
title: "Title"
transition: "none"
url: "file:///android_asset/www/index.html#page_settings"
__proto__: Object


4: Object
    hash: "#/android_asset/www/index.html?textbox_email=ffffg@hh.com"
    lastScroll: 0
    pageUrl: "/android_asset/www/index.html?textbox_email=ffffg@hh.com"
    title: "Title_new"
    transition: "fade"
    url: "file:///android_asset/www/index.html?textbox_email=ffffg@hh.com"
    __proto__: Object
    length: 5
    __proto__: Array[0]
```

`4: Object` is the object created after redirection and is different as compared to other objects like the Title is modified and the transition style is changed to `fade` from `none`.

Can any body please guide me why is it happening and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the go button is performing a submit action. What are you expecting to happen when the person hits go?

Can you track what's happening by debugging your code?

Comment: I expect nothing should happen when go button is clicked (or at least page redirection should not happen).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by adding  onsubmit='return false;' to the form tag in the following manner:

```
<form onsubmit='return false;'></form>
```